# How do I compile NetBSD kernel and userland with full debugging symbols

Tags: netbsd

I am compiling NetBSD kernel and userland for ARM in NetBSD5.1

Libraries generated are not with debugging symbols. Is there any kernel which I can use to enable debugging for userland?

For e.g. libc.so.12 is stripped. I want unstripped with full debugging symbols

Comment: Why an out of date version of NetBSD?  The current release version is 7.0, and the oldest supported release is 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

To build with debugging symbols, add -VMKDEBUG=yes and -VMKDEBUGLIB=yes to your build.sh command line.

See share/mk/bsd.README for all the available build flags.